# Firebase Authentication AUTHENTICATION_DISABLED error

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I'm working with angularfire, where I just want to implement authentication with firebase, but for some reason it keeps spitting out AUTHENTICATION_DISABLED error whenever I make a authWithPassword and createUser

I cloned the skeleton code from https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed

And it works fine when I run it in my local machine, however, after adding more functionalities, it doesn't work anymore.

Here is my code for login.js

```
"use strict";
angular.module('myApp.login', ['firebase.utils', 'firebase.auth', 'ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/login', {
  controller: 'LoginCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'login/login.html'
});
}])

.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', 'Auth', '$location', 'fbutil', function($scope, Auth, $location, fbutil) {
d3.select('svg').remove();
d3.select('svg').remove();

$scope.email = null;
$scope.pass = null;
$scope.confirm = null;
$scope.createMode = false;

$scope.login = function(email, pass) {
  $scope.err = null;
  Auth.$authWithPassword({ email: email, password: pass }, {rememberMe: true})
    .then(function(authData/* user */) {
      console.log("Logged in as : " + authData.uid);
      //$location.path('/account');
    }, function(err) {
      console.log("Error occured :(");
      $scope.err = errMessage(err);
    });
};

$scope.createAccount = function() {
  $scope.err = null;
  if( assertValidAccountProps() ) {
    var email = $scope.email;
    var pass = $scope.pass;
    // create user credentials in Firebase auth system
    Auth.$createUser({email: email, password: pass})
      .then(function() {
        // authenticate so we have permission to write to Firebase
        return Auth.$authWithPassword({ email: email, password: pass });
      })
      .then(function(user) {
        // create a user profile in our data store
        var ref = fbutil.ref('users', user.uid);
        return fbutil.handler(function(cb) {
          ref.set({email: email, name: name||firstPartOfEmail(email)}, cb);
        });
      })
      .then(function(/* user */) {
        // redirect to the account page
        console.log("User saved");
        //$location.path('/account');
      }, function(err) {
        console.log("Error in createAccount");
        $scope.err = errMessage(err);
      });
  }
};

function assertValidAccountProps() {
  if( !$scope.email ) {
    $scope.err = 'Please enter an email address';
  }
  else if( !$scope.pass || !$scope.confirm ) {
    $scope.err = 'Please enter a password';
  }
  else if( $scope.createMode && $scope.pass !== $scope.confirm ) {
    $scope.err = 'Passwords do not match';
  }
  return !$scope.err;
}

function errMessage(err) {
  return angular.isObject(err) && err.code? err.code : err + '';
}

function firstPartOfEmail(email) {
  return ucfirst(email.substr(0, email.indexOf('@'))||'');
}

function ucfirst (str) {
  // inspired by: http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
  str += '';
  var f = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
  return f + str.substr(1);
}
}]);
```

Any insight on why it's not working would be very helpful. If there is any information about dependencies I'll post them right away.

Comment: Is the user created at all or does that also fail?

Comment: Have you enabled email and password authentication from firebase console?

Comment: @Searching user created also fails

Comment: @ZuraSekhniashvili I have enabled email and password auth from firebase console

Comment: sorry i deleted my answer, just saw your comment on email/password. You mentioned it worked and then it doesn't. So before your changes you were able to create user and login ?